# Filtering by multiple values using XPath

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to filter an XML document of Jobs by the Company name.

I am able to pull all items that match specific Company names using:

```
doc.xpath("/source/job[company[text() = 'BigCorp' or text() = 'MegaCorp']]")
```

I am unable to do the opposite and exclude by these values, using something like:

```
doc.xpath("/source/job[company[text() != 'Hodes' or text() != 'Scurri']]")
```

Where am I going wrong?  Is there a way to provide a comma-separated list of values?

Comment: In short:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking, we need the minimum input data necessary to demonstrate the problem, along with the expected output. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `or` to `and`:

```
doc.xpath("/source/job[company[text() != 'Hodes' and text() != 'Scurri']]")
```

If you use `or`, it's always going to return the job.

For example, it would return the job with the company `Hodes` because `text() != 'Scurri'` is true (and vice versa).

---

Regarding the following comment:

> so `normalize-space()` did it!
>   `doc.xpath("/source/job[company[normalize-space() != 'Hodes' and normalize-space() != 'Scurri']]")` not sure why?

The reason `normalize-space()` worked is because `text()` is also going to return whitespace.

For example, if you have an element like:

```
<company>
 Hodes
</company>
```

or:

```
<company> Hodes </company>
```

the `text()` would equal "`_Hodes_`". (I replaced the spaces with `_` to make them easier to see.)

Because of the whitespace, "`_Hodes_`" doesn't equal "`Hodes`".

Using [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) will strip the leading/trailing whitespace and replace multiple spaces with a single space.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but it still returns those companies `doc = doc.xpath("/source/job[company[text() != 'Hodes' and text() != 'Scurri']]")`

Comment: @cman77 - Can you add a minimal example to your question? Maybe also try replacing `text()` with `normalize-space()`.

Comment: so `normalize-space()` did it!  `doc.xpath("/source/job[company[normalize-space() != 'Hodes' and normalize-space() != 'Scurri']]")`  not sure why?

Comment: @cman77 - Excellent! I'll update my answer with an explanation why that worked.